# How to use jQuery to identify a "change" event with many dynamic form elements

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have a web form that is built dynamically with dozens/hundreds of form element text fields.

Is there a way to use `$().change(function(){});` or some other method to (a) evoke jQuery/Ajax to do something in the background and to (b) capture which specific form element actually changes and use its changed value?

I can handle the Ajax portion. I have been unsuccessful with the onChange event.

Thanks.

* JS FILE LOOKS LIKE THIS ***

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; // needed for ajax to work in certain older browsers and versions

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a[rel^="prettyPhoto"]').prettyPhoto({
        changepicturecallback: function() {
            //alert('have focus');
        }
    });


//find all the form elements in your form,
//then bind an event handler to all of the elements for the `change` event
$('#my-form').find('input, textarea').on('change', function (event) {

    //this now refers to the "changed" element

    var name  = this.name,
        value = this.value,
        id    = this.id,
        dObj  = {};//create object to pass as data parameter to AJAX request

    //set the key as the name of the input, and the value as the value of the input
    dObj[name] = value;

    $.ajax({
        url     : '<url>',
        data    : dObj,//pass the data object
        //success : function (data) { ... },
        success : alert('changed CCC'),
        error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /*don't for get to deal with errors*/ }
    });
});


$('#my-form').on('change', 'input, textarea', function (event) {
    alert('changed AAA');
});



$(document).on('change', '#my-form input, #my-form textarea', function (event) {
    alert('changed BBB');
});



}); // end .ready()

//  window.parent.closePP();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
//find all the form elements in your form,
//then bind an event handler to all of the elements for the `change` event
$('#my-form').find('input, textarea').on('change', function (event) {

    //this now refers to the "changed" element

    var name  = this.name,
        value = this.value,
        id    = this.id,
        dObj  = {};//create object to pass as data parameter to AJAX request

    //set the key as the name of the input, and the value as the value of the input
    dObj[name] = value;

    $.ajax({
        url     : '<url>',
        data    : dObj,//pass the data object
        success : function (data) { ... },
        error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /*don't for get to deal with errors*/ }
    });
});
```

## Update

If you are adding the elements after the page-load, then you can use event delegation to bind to the elements that will be in the DOM:

```
$('#my-form').on('change', 'input, textarea', function (event) {
    ...
});
```

This assumes that the `#my-form` is in the DOM at the time of binding, otherwise you could bind to the `document`:

```
$(document).on('change', '#my-form input, #my-form textarea', function (event) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jasper. I tried all 3 versions of your answer and I can't get any of them to work. (see my code I just appended to my question). Note, I have placed the .JS file immediately before the closing </body> tag.

Comment: @Dr.DOT does your form have the ID of `my-form`? Because my JS code is trying to select `input` elements inside of the form with the ID of `my-form`. If the form doesn't have that ID, either change the selectors to find the correct form or give the form the `my-form` ID.